# How do I remove the browser video control in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

When you open the combined network and volume controls in Windows 11, above them is a control panel for videos recently played in your browser.  Trouble is, this sticks around even after you've left the page, the tab is closed or even closed the browser.  I'm having trouble finding anything on the web because all the terms I can think to use aren't right.  How can I get rid of it or change its behavior?

[image]

Comment: Not a Windows 11 user myself, but try disabling the 'Control media via keyboard, headset, or virtual interface' option under General > Browsing.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the answer. At least, after unchecking this box in FF and relogging in (to clear the existing control), it has not returned after viewing videos.

Comment: Also, I think you need to do the same thing with chrome/edge:  `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling`

Answer (score 2):

The lower block (wireless, brightness, audio, ...) is built into the Windows 11 task bar setup and is not natively changeable (not on any of my Windows 11 Pro machines in any event).

The controls for these functions (including Wireless) have moved into Settings.

The top box is Firefox related.  Check extensions. If removing extensions does not work, uninstall Firefox, restart and test the task bar operation .  Then install Firefox again. (There may be a Firefox update needed).

Comment: It definitely wasn't an extension or update (99.0b3 as of this post).  I think it may have been the "control media via keyboard..." option.

Answer (score 0):

According to this MS Community forum answer, it cannot be disabled globally, it has to be disabled on a per-application basis (thanks, Microsoft): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-the-media-bar-in-windows-11-system/50875288-9a2f-4df5-b66e-2667714b3497

> There is no global setting in Windows 11 to remove that media bar, it can only be done on an app by app basis:

I rewrote and expanded the details and I'm reposting here:

### Chrome

- Open Chrome
- In the Address bar, paste this and hit Enter: `chrome://flags`
- On the resulting page, type `media key` in the search box
- Disable `Hardware Media Key Handling`
- Restart Chrome

### Edge

Open Edge

- In the Address bar, paste this and hit Enter: `edge://flags`
- On the resulting page, type `media key` in the search box
- Disable `Hardware Media Key Handling`
- Restart Edge

### Firefox

- Go to Settings or enter `about:preferences` in the Address Bar
- Under General, scroll down to "Browsing" section or search for `media`
- Uncheck "Control media via keyboard, headset, or virtual interface"

### Spotify

- Go to Edit - Preferences
- Scroll down to the bottom of the basic settings
- In the Display Options, turn off 'Show desktop overlay when using media keys'